# Add a document inside an array that is inside another array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, insert, nosql

First I will give you a simple output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6016fcca3a406de622cfdc8f"),
    "pfname" : "charbel",
    "plname" : "alam",
    "address" : "Baskinta",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "phone" : "",
    "age" : "22",
    "addmissions" : [
            {
                    "sickness" : "diabete",
                    "arrival_date" : "13-1-2021",
                    "payments" : [ ]
            }
    ],
    "consultations" : [ ]
```

}

I am new to MongoDB and
I want to add a document inside the array "payments" which is inside the "addmissions" array

I have been trying this command:

```
db.patients.update( {"pfname":"charbel"}, {$set:{"addmissions": {"sickness":"diabete","arrival_date":"13-1-2021", {$push:{"payments":{"medicaments":[],"surgeries":[],"total_price":"100000","amount_paid":"60000","amount_left":"40000"}}} }} });
```

But I am getting the following error:
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{' :

I also tried something like this:

```
 db.patients.update({"pfname"
    :"charbel"},{$push:{addmissions.payments:{"medicaments":[],"surgeries":[],"total_price":"100000","amount_paid":"60000","amount_left":"40000"}}})
```

It is giving me this error:
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :

I also want to add a record to the medicaments array
I am trying this query:

```
db.patients.update({
"pfname":"charbel",
    "addmissions.sickness":"diabete",
        "addmissions.arrival_date":"13-1-2021",
        "addmissions.payments.total_price":"100000",
        "addmissions.payments.amount_paid":"60000",
        "addmissions.payments.amount_left":"40000"
        },{$push:{"addmissions.$.payments.medicaments":{"medname":"panadol","medprice":"30000"}}})



But it is giving me this error:
                "errms
```

g" : "Cannot create field 'medicaments' in element {payments: [ { medicaments: [], surgeries: [], total_price: "100000", amount_paid: "60000", amount_left: "40000" } ]}"

Comment: MongoDB uses [the dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document.

Comment: I edited my question, can you please check it out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>
);
```

**query:** The selection criteria for the update. If you intend to update a single document, made sure that these criteria are unique.

**update:** The modifications to apply. Here we uses the *dot notation* to access the elements of admissions array and to access the comments field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "pfname": "charbel",
  "addmissions.sickness": "diabete",
  "addmissions.arrival_date": "13-1-2021"
},
{
  $push: {
    "addmissions.$.payments": {
      "medicaments": [],
      "surgeries": [],
      "total_price": "100000",
      "amount_paid": "60000",
      "amount_left": "40000"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me why did you put the $ sign between addmissions and payments? Cause I am trying to add a document in the medicaments array

Comment: The [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html) operator projects the first matching array element from each document in a collection based on some condition from the query statement. Basically `$push` into the `payments` field of the first document in the `addmissions` array that match my query

Comment: Okay , thanks a lot! Can you please help with one more thing? How can I add a record to the medicaments array?

Comment: Read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with, if still having problem ask another question.